# Why does java Thread execute after the independent code?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am new to java and learning multi-threading. I wrote the following code.

```
class BackgroundTask implements Runnable {
    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        while (true) {
            this.setCounter(this.getCounter() + 1);
        }
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BackgroundTask bgTask = new BackgroundTask();

        Thread bgCount = new Thread(bgTask);

        try {
            
            bgCount.start();
            System.out.println("counter in background is running");
            
            bgCount.interrupt();
            System.out.println(bgTask.getCounter());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Output of the code:

```
counter in background is running
0
Thread started
```

Q.1 why is `bgCount.start()` executing after the print statement when it is written before it?

Q.2 Why did the thread start after calling the `getCounter()` method?

Edit: Thanks everyone for all the cool answers, now I understand the concept of threads.

Comment: Hi,you call start on a thread but that doesn't cause it to run, it just means it is eligible to be scheduled. Hence in this case all the other statements in your main method completed before the run method was scheduled.

Comment: `start()` doesnt start a thread in a synchronous blocking fashion. You have no control at all when a thread is executed exactly and in which order in relation to another threads operations things are executed. The OS scheduler determines when and which thread to give what many CPU time.

Comment: This is a "race condition" it's possible that 'Thread started' will be printed first if you run it enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

> Q.1 why is `bgCount.start()` executing after the print statement when it is written before it?

It is not, this is an incorrect conclusion. `start()` is executed exactly when you have written it. It just does not necessarily mean that the thread immediatly starts. The OS scheduler determines when to start a thread. The only guarantee that you get is that it will **eventually** start, so maybe now, maybe in a hour, maybe next year. Obviously, in practice it will usually be almost instant. But that does not mean it is executed as the very next thing.

> Q.2 Why did the thread start after calling the `getCounter()` method?
> As explained before, the OS scheduler decides. You just had *bad luck*. Seriously, you have no control over this and should not do any assumptions on this.

---

### Multi-threading

If you have multiple threads and they have a series of operations to execute, the OS scheduler is completely free to decide how to interleave the operations. That also means that not interleaving anything is valid as well.

Lets take a look at an example with thread `A` and `B` that have 2 operations to execute each. The following orders of executions are all valid outcomes of the scheduler:

```
A.1
A.2
B.1
B.2

A.1
B.1
A.2
B.2

A.1
B.1
B.2
A.2

B.1
B.2
A.1
A.2

B.1
A.1
B.2
A.2

B.1
A.1
A.2
B.2
```

So you must not make any assumptions about **when** a thread starts and especially not about in which **order** operations are executed in regards to other threads. It might be fully interleaved, might be sequential, might be partially interleaved, everything could happen.

If you want to take control over the mechanism, the correct tool is **synchronization**. With that you can tell that you want to wait for a certain thing to happen first in another thread before you continue. A very simple example for your above code would be to wait until `bgCount` is fully done before continuing to print the count. You can do so by using `join()`:

```
bgCount.start();
System.out.println("counter in background is running");
        
bgCount.join(); // waiting until down
System.out.println(bgTask.getCounter());
```

However, if you do it like that, you defeated the purpose of having a thread in the first place. There is no benefit in computing something *in-parallel* if you completely block the other thread and wait. Then it is basically just like executing something in the ordinary **sequential** way.

Comment: Re, "...not interleaving anything..." What you call "not interleaving" is, in fact, one of the many possible interleavings. It's just like how we say that zero is a number, even though it it obvious to anybody who has _not_ studied math that "zero apples" is not a number of apples or; how we say that the empty set is a set even though it is obviously not a set of anything.

Comment: Correct. I thought it might be easier to understand by phrasing it like that. Thanks for the addition though.

Answer (score 3):

When you do things in two different threads, they are unsynchronized unless you force some kind of synchronization. One thread might execute first or the other thread might or they might interleave in unpredictable ways. That's kind of the point of threads.